How can I make a biodegradable large wooden container that is waterproof?
I am looking for a way to make a large wooden container , about 2mx2mx1.2m (Sides x Height), built out of wood, hold water. Everything involved in the construction has to be 100% biodegradable. The container or waterproofness do not have to last a long time. I was thinking about constructing the container out of wood planks and then line or coat the inside with something waterproof so it can hold the water. Does anybody know any matertial that is reasonably waterproof and biodegradable that I could use? I have searched online but have not found anything useful so far.

I often find practices from pre-plastic civilisation useful for finding biodegradeable ways of doing things. I wonder if you could take inspiration from oakum (hemp/just rope and pine tar)? To waterproof wooden ships you can ram the rope into the gaps and seal with the pitch/tar.

That is actually a stonking great idea. I will investigate this further. Thanks very much!

Yeah I mean storing (and aging) wine which is pretty similar to water is a tried and tested method well known since centuries. AFAIK they manage the waterproofing by having fitting wooden beams tightly held together by metal bands and do not even use tar or anything else.

The first thing that comes to mind is a solution that I understand was invented over 2000 yrs ago (at least, early versions of it) - the barrel.
I expect the circular shape allows the planks to be bound together very tightly to close up gaps. It sounds like the iron bands used to hold together more modern barrels made a big difference to their reliability, and though iron isn't biodegradable, it will still break down.
This may help further: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_(profession)
